# Custom button image not fit inside shapeDrawable

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-button

I try to create a custom button as circle and set background image for the circle.So I extends Button class and set ShapeDrawable with OvalShape.And create a LayerDrawable and add this shape and add a background image. But the image not fit inside the first layer(Circle shape).How to fit the image on background of Circle shape?

```
mOvalDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
                    mOvalDrawable.getPaint().setColor(drawableBackgroundColor);

Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.facebook);
drawable.setBounds(mOvalDrawable.getBounds());

//ClipDrawable clipDrawable = new ClipDrawable(drawable, Gravity.LEFT, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);

LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{drawable,mOvalDrawable});

                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    {
                        //setBackground(mOvalDrawable);
                        setBackground(layerDrawable);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //setBackgroundDrawable(mOvalDrawable);
                        setBackgroundDrawable(layerDrawable);
                    }
```

[image]

Comment: I am trying to create a round shape button with custom background image...here drawable is an image...

Comment: where is that image?

Comment: The image is available in drawable folder.And add the drawable to LayerDrawable with ShapeDrawable. And then set this LayerDrawable to backGround of button.is it right way to achieve my goal?

Comment: post an image of **your button**

Comment: Added image on my question.

Comment: Can you also post the image you want to create?

Comment: Just create a button as Circle(using ShapeDrawable) and set background of the circle as above facebook image.I am not having any design for that.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a CircleImage to achieve the goal. You can refer to this project [in github.](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView)